# StringBuilder append same char multiple times

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

Is there a fast way to append a `StringBuilder` multiple times in C#? Of course I can write my own extension to append in loop, but it looks ineffective.

Comment: Can you show the code you already got? What are you trying to achieve? Why is it ineffektive? Peformance/Memory?

Comment: Because it is a simple `for`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[There is already an `Append` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxyxbz2e.aspx) that accepts `char value` and `int repeatCount`:

```
char c = ...
int count = ...
builder.Append(c, count);
```

or more simply (in many cases):

```
builder.Append(' ', 20);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use string constructor

```
sb.Append(new String('a', 3)); // equals  sb.Append("aaa")
```

Comment: I did not know StringBuilders append overload stated by Marc. It is obviously better (:

Answer (score 1):

`StringBuilder` has a constructor lile [`StringBuilder.Append Method (Char, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxyxbz2e.aspx)

> Appends a **specified number of copies** of the string representation of a
>   Unicode character to this instance.

Like `StringBuilder.Append(char value, int repeatCount)`

For example;

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append('*', 10);
Console.WriteLine(sb);
```

Output will be;

```
**********
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/381apM).